# Find all abelian groups that fit in a given short exact sequence.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

I have to find all abelian groups that can appear in this short exact sequence.

$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_5 \rightarrow 0 $

First of all since both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_5$ are finitely generated we get that $A$ must be finitely generated as well. So we can use the classification of finitely generated groups.

I can compute some cases but I have no clue of how to prove that these are the only ones. I tried to extend the diagram and the apply some sort of nine lemma with an upper row given by:

$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}^{3} \rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow 0$

I can make both rows conmutative but I  don't have enough information. Any tips? I know I could use $\mathrm{Ext}$ but I'm not supposed to know that.

Comment: The free rank is determined to be 2. The torsion part can be 0 by using multiplication by 5 or Z5 by killing a free factor.

Comment: Could you elaborate this in an answer please?

Comment: In other words, the free factor in the quotient must split, so $A$ has a subgroup $Z^2$ with quotient $Z_5$. This extension either splits, in which case $A = Z^2 \oplus Z_5$, or it doesn't split, in which case $A = Z^2$.